# Getting 404 error while running API for moving google events from one calendar to another

Tags: google-calendar-api, zapier

I am using a proper calendar id and a proper event id still I am getting the error, I don't know why.
The tool I am using to perform HTTP request is zapier.

I tried running the API request via Zapier and directly from the google api dashboard. None worked.

Comment: body
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "notFound",
"message": "Not Found"
}
],
"code": 404,
"message": "Not Found"
}
}

This is what I am getting as response.